# How would I count the comparisons made in a Binary Search Tree?

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I was wondering how I would add a counter that represents the number of comparisons in my BST. I added a counter but my printTree function for some reason I keep getting 0 for the count. Am I suppose to count the number of comparisons made in the print function? Or should I have a separate function specifically for counting the number of comparisons made?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
  int data;
  node* left;
  node* right;
};
node* root = NULL;


node* createLeaf(int data)
{
  node* n = new node;
  n->data = data;
  n->left = NULL;
  n->right = NULL;

  return n;
}
void addLeaf(node* &curr, int data)
{

  //If curr = NULL then add node
  if(curr == NULL)
    {
      curr = createLeaf(data);

    }


  //Left(Less than)
  else if(data <= curr->data)
    {
      addLeaf (curr->left, data);

    }
  //Right(greater than)
  else if(data >= curr->data)
    {
      addLeaf(curr->right, data);

    }


}

int printTree(node* Ptr, ofstream& NewData, int count)
{

    //Check if tree is empty
  if(root != NULL)
    {
        return count++;
      if(Ptr->left != NULL)
        {
            printTree(Ptr->left, NewData, count);
        }
      NewData << Ptr->data; //Store Data in output file
      NewData << endl;
      cout << Ptr->data << " ";
      if(Ptr->right != NULL)
        {
            printTree(Ptr->right, NewData, count);
        }
    }

  else
    {
      cout << "The Tree is empty\n";
    }

    return Ptr->data;

}

int main()
{

    ifstream dataFile;
    dataFile.open("Data.txt.");
    int temp, count;
    count = 0;

    while(dataFile)
    {
        dataFile >> temp;
        addLeaf(root, temp);
    }

    dataFile.close();


    ofstream NewData;
    NewData.open("NewData.txt");

    count = printTree(root, NewData, count);
    cout << "count:" << count;

    NewData.close();






  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh. 1. `int` is passed by value, and at the same time you use it as function return value. 2. You make a return in the beginning of your method. BST isn't working now.

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass the count variable by reference (Or use a pointer. Example uses pass by reference) and then increment without returning and this will give you a simple way of counting the number of comparisons. Edited snippets of your code are below.

**Note:** For future reference post incrementing value to be returned will do nothing if it is being returned. e.g. use `return ++count;` instead of `return count++;`. This is why you where getting zero as the value of your count variable. A simple way of explaining this behavior is that when you return a post-incremented value it returns the value and exists that function before incrementing it. Although from what I understand of the code you did not really want to be returning the count variable.

```
int printTree(node* Ptr, ofstream& NewData, int &count)
{                                           //  ^ The & specifies that is to be passed
                                            //  by reference.

    //Check if tree is empty
  if(root != NULL)
    {
     // No longer returns instead just increments.
     count++;
     // Your code here.
    }
    // Your code here.
}

int main()
{

    int count = 0;
    // The rest of your code here ....

    // Stores the return value from print tree root "ptr->data"
    int data = 0;

    // New caller will modify count as it is passed by reference, but will "return ptr->data;"
    data = printTree(root, NewData, count);
    cout << "count:" << count;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it by defining a tiny class that was devoted primarily to counting comparisons:

```
template <class T>
struct holder {
   static int count;

   T t;

   holder(T T) : t(t) {}
   operator T() const { return t; }

   operator <(T const &r) { ++count; return t < r.t; }
};

int holder::count = 0;
```

Then a node would hold instances of these instead of holding `int`s directly:

```
struct node { 
    holder<int> data;
    node *left;
    node *right;
};
```

Do your work with your tree, and when you want to know the number of comparisons you've done so far, look at `holder<int>::count;` to get it.